# UISearchcontroller Cancel button not working

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller, uisearchbardelegate

```
class PlaceSelectorViewController: UIViewController, GMSAutocompleteResultsViewControllerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate {
```

I have UISearchBarDelegate in my class

```
searchController?.searchBar.delegate = self
```

and I had set the delegate to Self.

```
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    stopHighlight()
}
```

But this Delegate call is not working

Comment: When are you calling this: searchController?.searchBar.delegate = self ?
Are you searchController already exists there ?

Comment: are you setting the delegate in the viewDidLoad() ?

Comment: There is no other variable called searchController and Delegate has setted on viewDidLoad()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an `outleet` for your UISearchBar (assuming you're working with Storyboard this is really easy, just drag and drop via Assistant Editor). and that's what you're going to add the delegate to. In case you built programmatically, then that variable is the one that's going to get assigned to the delegate.

Here's the example code for the *Storyboard* built

`@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!` (you must see a filled circle at the right of this, otherwise there's no link between *Storyboard* and this *outlet*)

...

`override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    searchBar.delegate = self
}`